# Подскажите как правильно осуществить запрос из двух(нескольких) коллекций mongodb + spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

При попытках работать с mongodb + spring столкнулся с проблемой осуществления одного запроса к нескольким таблицам. 
Суть вопроса такова, что есть User и Car и у каждого юзера может быть несколько Car

`User
    {
       "_id": "5d70e28c51807419cca9f291",
       "name": "Анджела Валерьевна Покобатько",
        "email": "reggg999@mail.ru",
        "cars": {
            0:"5d70e28c51807419cca9f29b",
            1:"5d70e28c51807419cca9f29c"
        }
    }
    Car
    {
         "_id": "5d70e28c51807419cca9f29b",
         "name": "Toyota Corolla",
    }`

Т.е. у юзера хранятся id его каров
Столкнулся с тем, что за 2 дня так и не смог нагуглить внятного решения, как сделать запрос который вернет мне объект типа
`User
    {
       "_id": "5d70e28c51807419cca9f291",
       "name": "Анджела Валерьевна Покобатько",
        "email": "reggg999@mail.ru",
        "cars": {
            {
                 "_id": "5d70e28c51807419cca9f29b",
                 "name": "Toyota Corolla",
            },
            {
                 "_id": "5d70e28c51807419cca9f29b",
                 "name": "Mazda 6",
            }
        }
    }`

Реализовал подобное при помощи аннотации @DBRef, но потом прочитал, что данная аннотация не рекомендована к использованию.
Так же можно осуществить подобное при использовании аннотации @Reference, но тогда бд будет хранить в объекте связанные с ним объекты, что будет увеличивать размер базы данных.
Есть еще вариант вначале получить первой транзакцией всех юзеров, из них получить id каров, и потом отдельной транзакцией получить всех каров для данных юзеров.

СОБСТВЕННО ВОПРОСЫ

1. Возможно ли осуществить запрос, описанный выше
2. Какой из подходов является правильным при работе со связанными коллекциями в mongodb?

Comment: Тут 2 варианта. Либо вы на уровне приложения подгружаете данные из 2-ой коллекции и объединяете их (с  dbref это будет делаться автоматически). Либо используйте агрегацию(шаг называется graphLookup), которая позволит сделать left join.

Comment: @aleshka-batman я видел много примеров запросов с lookup где можно сделать условие where c учетом данных второй коллекции, но не видел ни одного примера, где можно получить в результат запроса объекты из другой коллекции (в моем случае Car). не могли бы вы привести пример подобного запроса?

Comment: @aleshka-batman сорри. смотрел просто lookup. graphLookup то, что нужно. Спасибо!